# Python - remove elements from array if element contains a partial match with elements in another array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm looking for a way to filter all elements in an array if the element contains a substring that occurs in another filter-array. Below is an example:

```
target = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
filter = ["ree","wo"]
```

The following snippet works if the substrings array is a string and not an array

```
filter = "wo"
filtered_target = [string for string in target if filter in string]
```

However, I want it to remove all elements from the target array that contain substrings provided in the filter array. How could I approach this elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function -

```
target = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
filters = ["ree","wo"]

filterd_list = [s for s in target if not any(f in s for f in filters)]
```

this would remove all strings from target which have one of the filters as a substring, output -

```
['one', 'four', 'five']
```

Comment: Thank you Jay!
I was looking at the any function but couldn't wrap my head around using it in a single line of code, this works perfectly